# Thumbnail extraction from videos using Qt/C++

Tags: qt

how to get thumbnail image from the video file using Qt/C++.i use TagLib ,its not worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the libVLC or ffmpeg, it's more easily than using Qt

Answer (score 0):

Basically any Video is in 'frame' and that frame is you thumbnail.

We can image like box, where inside of box are all information about 'image' like where is positioned (in time), how big it is (Full HD, 720 ...), and all other sort of information.

Biggest question is what video format you like to extract, and how you like to extract.

For example file format like AVI is well known see:
[how to read avi files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899444/how-to-read-avi-files-c)

In case when you read som other format, you need to know how to read correctly in binary format, or you can use any library that will handle 'unpack format' for you.

Last question is if library can 'extract' image for 'this' frame ... but this is up to library.

To answer your question, you can use any external library, or read manually by yourself on binary level.

PS: If TagLib is not working for you can try any other library, just make sure you read documentation and try to find is library allow you to get images from frames.